# Wordpress change sub-category class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble with my WordPress site.

I have a page displaying my categories and sub-categories.
They are displayed in a `<ul>`.

Now I want to give the sub-categories a class to style them differently.

Is this possible with a walker maybe?

I can't change the template because it's is loaded in via a plugin (Events manager)

EDIT:
the HTML that is generated:

```
<ul>
<li>Category</li>
<li>sub-Category</li>
<li>sub-Category</li>
<li>Category</li>
<li>sub-Category</li>
<li>sub-Category</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you copy paste the HTML here that is generated?

Comment: Your HTML snippet doesn't indicate any subcategories.

Comment: That's the point. The plugin doesn't put the sub categories inside the parent

Comment: In that case, I think you're out of luck. I'd suggest contacting the plugin author to ask for help -- they hold the key to their poor HTML output. If you always know the exact order of categories and subcategories, you could use the [:nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) selector in CSS, but I think this has issues in IE8.

Comment: Thanks. I can't know the exact order because the customer can add categories

Comment: It is now solved. A back-end developer here rewrote the object that the plugin passes on to a custom array so now I can do with the structure I want ;D

Answer (score 0):

> I can't change the template because it's is loaded in via a plugin (Events manager)

It depends on the plugin. You should look at the documentation for your plugin. Some plugins will load a default template but allow you to override it with one of your own in your theme. The plugin may provide a filter that allows you to customize the output, but this seems like a very specific customization you're not likely to find.

Did you know you can target child `<ul>` elements in CSS without a class? For instance, the following would target only `<ul>` elements that are nested under a `<ul>` element:

```
ul ul {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well ofcourse I know how to target childs. The plugin doesn't give you the option to make the sub categories a "sub ul" it is just a <UL> with all the categories in it. Not a <ul> with <li> that contain <ul> for the sub items. And ive read the documentation. Ive been working with the plugin for about a month now(big website).